# What if we split the array in merge sort into 4 parts?? or eight parts?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I came across this question in one of the slides of Stanford, that what would be the effect on the complexity of the code of merge sort if we split the array into 4 or 8 instead of 2.

Comment: In terms of big-O, it would make no difference. Either way it's O(N log N). The base of the logarithm would change from 2 to 4 or 8, but the base of the logarithm is irrelevant to complexity.

Answer (score 3):

It would be the same: `O(n log n)`. You will have a shorter tree and the base of the logarithm will change, but that doesn't matter for big-oh, because a logarithm in a base `a` differs from a logarithm in base `b` by a constant:

```
log_a(x) = log_b(x) / log_b(a)
1 / log_b(a) = constant
```

And big-oh ignores constants.

You will still have to do `O(n)` work per tree level in order to merge the `4` or `8` or however many parts, which, combined with more recursive calls, might just make the whole thing even slower in practice.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can split your array into equal size subarrays of any size and then sort the subarrays recursively, and then use a min-heap to keep extracting the next smallest element from the collection of sorted subarrays. If the number of subarrays you break into is constant, then the execution time for each min-heap per operation is constant, so you arrive at the same O(n log n) time.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively it would be the same as there is no much difference between splitting the array into two parts and then doing it again or splitting it to 4 parts from the beginning.

A more official proof by induction based on [this](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/04Sorting.pdf) (I'll assume that the array is split into k):

```
Definitions:     
  Let T(N) - number of array stores to mergesort of input of size N
  Then mergesort recurrence T(N) = k*T(N/k) + N (for N > 1, T(1) = 0)

Claim: 
  If T(N) satisfies the recurrence above then T(N) = Nlg(N)
  Note - all the logarithms below are on base k 

Proof:
  Base case: N=1 
  Inductive hypothesis: T(N) = NlgN
  Goal: show that T(kN) = kN(lg(kN))

  T(kN) = kT(N) + kN              [mergesort recurrence]
        = kNlgN + kN              [inductive hypothesis]
        = kN(lg[(kN/k)]           [algebra]
        = kN(lg(kN) - lgk)        [algebra]
        = kN(lg(kN) - 1) + kN     [algebra - for base k, lg(k )= 1]
        = kNlg(kN)                [QED]
```

Comment: I'd expect the merge step to be 2N in case of 4-split, and 3N for 8-split (not that it changes the complexity, it doesn't).

Comment: The overall number of comparisons is supposed to be the same as you got less recursion levels for the comparisons. In other words, for a k-way split you indeed got lg(k) comparisons to make, but this is the same as you did a 2-way split and then you had to make the comparisons in lg(k) levels.

Comment: we should solve `T(n)=2*T(n/2)+n` vs.  e.g. `T(n)=8*T(n/8)+3*n` directly, to see this for sure. the first seems to be `n*logBase(2,n)`, the second `3*n*logBase(8,n)` (right?)  which is the same, so, yes.